# Why I am getting 404 Page Not Found in my NextJS 13 app?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, custom-error-pages

I have been learning Next.js 13. I have encountered an unusual error when I start the app for the first time. The pages are shown properly. But if I close it and reopen the application again, it starts showing a page not found.

##### My folder structure

[image: My folder structure]

##### My homepage page.tsx

[image: My homepage page.tsx]

##### Terminal

[image: Terminal]

##### Output + Console

[image: Output + Console]

I just ran the application just like any other normal app. I was expecting to see the contents of my page, but it's showing the page not found error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because you have the app directory in the root and in the `src` directory. You made a route in `src/app/page.tsx` but Next.js will not read your `src` if there is `<ROOT>/app` so it's not found.

Remove the extra `app` directory

Answer (score 0):

Same issue that i dealing with but steel not resolve.